# GROUP BY Multiple columns each on

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this table:

```
id   | word1   | word2
1    |  100    | 200
2    |  101    | 200
```

I want to show the `word_number` values only one time, for example, for the current table - here`s my expected result:

```
100, 101, 200
```

I have tried this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT word1, word2 FROM table GROUP BY word1, word2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $start,$perpage);
$stmt->execute();
```

in this way its group only the word1, so the result its:

```
100, 200, 101, 200
```

When I change the `GROUP BY` to `word2` its correct, but its to opposite.

### More explain for the question:

```
id   | word1   | word2
1    |  100    | 200
2    |  101    | 200
```

for this table, `id` row its primary key, its mean grow every row.
so for word1 = 100, word2 = 200 - the `id` value its `1` - I want to `ORDER BY` this `id` key.

Comment: why not using two seperate query? because group by on both would return the couple of value, not group by word1 then by word 2

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT word1 word FROM my_table UNION SELECT word2 FROM my_table;`

Comment: @MacBooc I think about it, is this efficient? If their isnt any another way I will use this.

Comment: @Strawberry when I try to `bind_result` the results of your query, its give me an empty.. `$stmt->bind_result($word1, $word2);`

Comment: efficient ? it'll require more reading yeah, but with you structure, i'm not sure you'll find really more efficient for this task

Comment: There's no word1 or word2 here. There is only word.

Comment: @Strawberry So how can I `bind_result` this?

Comment: At a guess... `$stmt->bind_result($word);`

Comment: @Strawberry Oh, I write wrong - how can I `ORDER BY` it? When I set `ORDER BY id DESC` the query not run.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @Strawberry in `my_table` every row have a primary key named `id`, I want to show the result by `ORDER BY id DESC` but the when I do it the query dont work.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. There are two ids associated with '200', so which one do we use for the sorting?

Comment: @Strawberry I will make it clear. this the table: `id|word1|word2` - the id its common to both `word1` and `word2`. I want to `ORDER BY id DESC` that it commom.

Comment: Nope. Still not clear to me. Which id does 200 belong to, and why?

Comment: @Strawberry I edit my question and add ## More explain for the question:

Comment: Unfortunately, you're just repeating what you've already said in the comments. So, I'm none the wiser.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need the result to be sorted by the ID?
Then you could use a normal `UNION` with a select for both word fields.

A normal `UNION` already discards duplicates, so it won't need a `GROUP BY` then.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT word1 as word FROM table UNION SELECT word2 FROM table ORDER BY word DESC LIMIT ?, ?');
```

And if it does need to be sorted by the ID, then using a `UNION ALL` wouldn't remove the dups. So you can group & sort from a sub-query.

Then the Query could be something like this:

```
SELECT word 
FROM
(
  SELECT id, word1 as word
  FROM table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, word2
  FROM table
) q
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
LIMIT ?, ?
```

Or by using the `CROSS JOIN` to numbers trick.

```
select case n when 1 then word1 when 2 then word2 end as word
from table
cross join (select 1 n union all select 2) N
group by word
order by min(id) desc
limit ?, ?
```

Comment: I need the result sorted by `id` (the primary key) :)

Comment: I thought you would need a DISTINCT in the first SELECT, but I've just checked, and actually your query is correct (except that the question has moved on)

Comment: @AmandaWhite Added an extra query.  But I assume someone might come up with a more performant solution.

Comment: @LukStorms Okay I will wait, thanks for helping - for now I will try to understand your query.